# Zend 2 Action get called twice

Tags: zend-framework, action

I guess it's time for ask help.
My zend 2 action called twice. But it does not get called twice if it is internet Explorer.Tried to disable firebug but still the same.I saw other threads but did not find any suitable solution for me.

Update:
The other thread I have seen that seems to be useful is
[Zend 2 Action get called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851384/zend-2-action-get-called-twice)
But the problem does not go away.

Comment: Maybe one of them is AJAX call just before ordinary call?

Comment: @DanielGadawski: I have removed all the project code to identify the reason. There is no Ajax call. Even there is no CSS and HTML files included currently just to find the reason. But still the Zend Action calls twice.

Comment: Is there anyone else to replying with more solutions?